# Does a French long stay research visa differ from a regular "Type-D" visa and are there implications for travelling in Schengen areas?

Tags: schengen, france, long-stay-visas

I'll be going to France for 4 months to conduct research towards my PhD. I believe I will be issued with a long stay visa for research to cover my trip. I have the required "Convention d’Accueil" from the organisation I'll be spending time at. I currently hold an Australian passport.

My question is, is this research visa considered a "Type D", like the other French long stay visas and does it allow entry into other Schengen areas? Does the research visa carry any specific conditions (besides the fact that you need a "Convention d’Accueil" to apply)?

I will have a month off during my 4 month stay, during which I'd like to travel around to other countries, hopefully I can do this with the one visa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I visit Schengen countries on a long term French Visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11114/can-i-visit-schengen-countries-on-a-long-term-french-visa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I visit Schengen countries on a Type-D Schengen Visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19147/can-i-visit-schengen-countries-on-a-type-d-schengen-visa)

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19147/can-i-visit-schengen-countries-on-a-type-d-schengen-visa?rq=1

Comment: Hey guys, I agree it could be a duplicate, but my main concern was whether the specific research visa has the same conditions as the other type D long stay visas?

Comment: @MitchellD Try editing your question to make sure it differs from the two linked duplicates.

Comment: @JoErNanO, have made some edits, as per your suggestion

Comment: @MitchellD Looks good to me now. Will retract my close vote. On a different note, where in France will you be going?

Comment: @JoErNanO thanks :) i'll be based in Grenoble mostly, I'm doing some work at the European Synchrotron Radiation Facility

Comment: The research you described falls under a type "D" visa, but given that your stay is 4 months they have the OPTION of issuing a Schengen. In either case you can travel around the zone unless the visa itself shows a restriction (which is rare). There's no way of telling what the consulate will do, and you will know when you inspect the visa.  Was that your question?

Comment: @GayotFow you nailed it. That's what I was after.

Comment: @MitchellD do you want someone to write a 'formal' answer in case somebody has the question in the future? Or do you now believe that your question is duplicated by those above?

Comment: @GayotFow go ahead and put your comment as an answer. I think it will be good to explicitly say that the research visa is still classed as type D and can be used in schengen areas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The research you described falls under a type "D" (national) visa, but given that your stay is 4 months they have the *OPTION* of issuing a Schengen. In either case you can travel around the zone unless the visa itself shows a restriction (which is rare). There's no way of telling what the consulate will do, and you will know when you inspect the visa.

Comment: just to follow up on this. I've been issued the type D visa, it says "valid for: France (sauf CTOM) and number of entries "MULT". Does this mean I am able to enter any country in the Schengen area as many times as I like?

Comment: Yes, that's the meaning of "MULT"