# Why does my visa say valid for Deutschland instead of Schengen?

Tags: visas, germany, schengen-visas

Usually I have seen that the valid for is “Schengen State” and the type of visa is “C” with Number of entries “Multiple.”

But, in my case, it's written as valid for “Deutschland “ and the type of visa is "C."

Seriously, I don’t know how my visa got stamped as this one. I was expecting it would be “Schengen State.”

Can I travel outside of Germany, in other Schengen states, or not?

Comment: I would call whoever issued this and ask. I am not knowledgeable enough to state this with certainty but here I thought the C visas were issued Schengen wide and D visas were country specific. But the latter allows https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/11119/4188 travel Schengen wide too. It makes no sense to issue a country specific C visa.

Comment: Your visa is only meant to enter Germany and none else unfortunately. http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/what-does-my-sticker-visa-mean If the mark is “FRANCE”, the visa entitles you **only** to enter French territory.

Comment: @chx It is not unheard of at all to issue a country specific C visa

Comment: @chx Type C visas with limited territorial validity can be issued for any of a number of reasons. They are governed by article 25 of the [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412).

Answer (score 9):

You were issued a *limited territorial validity* visa (LTV), which likely means you didn't actually fulfil all the Schengen criteria, but given the purpose of your trip, they chose to issue some visa anyway.

LTV visas are rather uncommon (they're most commonly issued as emergency visas on arrival), and you will usually be refused a visa altogether if not fulfilling all requirements. You can try asking the embassy the reason for the LTV visa: however, it is likely they'll tell you to take a hike, as they're not obliged to explain themselves (and often won't).

So no, you are **not** allowed to travel outside of Germany. Especially don't try to go to France, or by land to Denmark, Sweden or Switzerland, as it's likely you'll actually be checked at the border.

Comment: Wow. I now read the relevant Wikipedia article saying "Despite the fact that LTV visas may be issued in exceptional cases only, some member state abuse the facility. For instance, the Spanish Embassy in Russia occasionally issues LTV visas to tourists."

Comment: What makes you think it's about “risk”? That doesn't fully make sense. If the consulate suspects the person might abscond and stay illegally, a LTV visa provides very little protection. The person will obviously be able to enter the country and stay there and in practice going to another country isn't very difficult so it doesn't protect other Schengen countries.

Comment: In principle, LTV visas are about allowing countries to ignore some legal requirements set by the Schengen visa code. For example, it can be used to let someone who fails to meet the financial requirements enter anyway for humanitarian reasons. Or it can be used to overcome the objections of other member states or length of stay restrictions for political reasons (think Syrian negotiators coming to Geneva or something).

Comment: @Crazydre Everything you wrote after “in the sense” sounds reasonable but it is not at all what the word “risk” suggests.

Comment: Why not actually remove the confusing parts and make the parentheses the main clauses?

Comment: Might be worth putting the answer to the OP's question directly - i.e. no OP cannot travel outside Germany with this (LTV) visa. Though there are no border controls, but if checked he will be considered to be "visa-less" outside Germany.

Comment: @RedBaron Updated

Comment: @RedBaron "Though there are no border controls" Not true everywhere