# Can my daughter visit Germany on her Type D Schengen visa issued by France?

Tags: france, schengen-visas, long-stay-visas

I know this has been asked a few times, I'm just trying to confirm that my understanding is correct. According to [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11114/88029), she should be able to travel to Germany for a short holiday on her multiple entry, type-D Schengen visa, even though the visa states:

Valid for: FRANCE (+1 TRANSIT SCHENGEN)

Edit: If I wasn't clear, I'm asking about the fact that the visa specifically states that it is valid for France, and if that somehow trumps the general type-D travel allowance. I didn't find a clear answer to that part. Possibly just because I don't understand the EU rules.

Comment: Once she's stamped into France for the first time, yes, she's allowed to travel to other Schengen countries including Germany for short visits.

Comment: Thanks @Giorgio, that question has a similar answer to the one I linked in my question. The crux of my question revolves around the fact that it specifically states that it is valid for France, which is only indirectly addressed in the other questions.

Comment: The rules are the same throughout: she has a long stay visa, issued by France (with the added notation that she can travel there with one connection in another Schengen country, if necessary. After arrival in France, she can stay in France as long as permitted by her visa, and can travel through the Schengen area, per the 90-180 rules. phoog's answer in the covers that nicely.

Comment: So the Valid for: FRANCE, is in relation to her long term visa being valid for France, but for travel purposes it is valid anywhere in the Schengen area, subject to the 90/180 rules?