# Travelling outside Germany with only a German D visa in the absence of a residence permit

Tags: visas, schengen, germany

I have a long-term German National D Visa for research.

I have an upcoming short trip outside Germany to the Schengen Zone but I don't have a residence permit yet. I've been informed that I should get the residence permit before travelling abroad but that is contrary to what I've been reading online i.e. the D visa can be used for short-term stays in European countries outside Germany.
https://visaguide.world/europe/germany-visa/long-stay/

Does anyone have experience regarding this issue or can tell if I am allowed to travel outside Germany?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I visit other Schengen countries on a long-term Schengen visa or residency permit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11114/can-i-visit-other-schengen-countries-on-a-long-term-schengen-visa-or-residency-p)

Comment: Important would be to apply for the residence permit as soon as practical (within 3 months after arrival). Once applied for (i. e. the main purpose of the D-Visa) you can use that for short term visits until the actual resident permit has been issued.

Answer (score 0):

**Type D: National visa or visa for research purposes.**

You are required to stay in Germany for longer than three months within the six-month period after your first entry. Any person in possession of a National visa and valid travel documents are permitted to move freely in the Schengen area for up to three months in any six-month period.

**NOTE:** A Type D National visa can be converted into a residence permit after entry into Germany. However, you must still actively apply for your residence permit after entering the country.**You will need to convert your visa into a residence permit within three months of arriving in Germany.**

It shouldn't be a problem for you to travel inside Schengen countries as I rarely see visa check-in airport if you are travelling inside the EU from any Schengen country. Your plane ticket is enough if you are flying else you can simply use a train or other means for travel where they don't go through visa unless you don't commit any illegal activities.