Can Americans get standard visas instead of going visa-free
As a tourist born in the states, can I apply for a regular visa to a Schengen country instead of getting a Schengen visa? I am wondering if I can stay in each country for 90 days without having to leave the Schengen zone, maybe if I get standard visas and not a Schengen visa?

A Schengen visa grants the same options as the visa-free entry on the US passport, so it just makes no sense. There's no "each country for 90 days" limit, the 90/180 rule is for all of Schengen. There's no "regular" or "standard" visa for "each country". All the Schengen countries grant the exact same type of visa for tourism.

Why do you want to be able to do this? Work? Extended holiday? Retire? There are 27 countries in the EU, do you really want to spend 90 days in each one by turn?

You should get a visa in this case. However, as mentioned in the comments a regular tourist visa (or even multiple ones) won't make a difference because the 90/180 day rule will apply for the whole Schengen area in the same manner as the visa-free entry.
In this case you should apply for a visa that allows a stay longer than 90 days, such as a working holiday visa or a digital nomad visa. This page has some info about it (is really poorly written, but it has a lot of information), every country has its own rules, but most likely you can travel around the whole Schengen area with a single visa.
In some cases you can also enter the country without a visa and apply for an extension later.

"digital nomad" visas, where exist, are national visas and do not apply to any other country. They don't allow circumventing the 90/180 rule outside of the country of residency (the one that issued the long stay visa).

You are technically correct on paper, but the real world is different, you can check this answer and the comments for more info: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/11119/138206

@André The fact that the rules are rarely enforced via systematic border checks does not mean they are not enforced at all or that it is legal. In many situations, it can actually be very easy to find out someone has gone over the 90/180 limit even without stamps.

@jcaron I've been living in the Schengen area for three years.  The number of times I've had to identify myself aside from at an external border crossing (where a national visa or residence permit will be enough) has been exactly zero.  I doubt that many people will have much probability of being caught unless they're living permanently in a country other than the one they have permission to live in and are furthermore doing something else that causes them to come to the attention of the police.

Adding to what phoog said: 1 - One is allowed 90 days, so the checks would need to happen several times over this period before anything (potentially nonconforming) is noticed. 2 - The OP is not spending over 90 days in a single place.

So basically you're suggesting someone to violate laws under the assumption they wouldn't be caught. That's not generally something that's allowed on Stack Exchange. Suggesting someone to break the law with the justification "look at me, I've done it and haven't been caught" is also somewhat stupid.

@phoog I have been living in the Schengen area for 12 years, and several times I have been checked on internal Schengen borders, which vary with circumstance, currently until Today there are border checks in German borders due to the UEFA EURO 2024, you can see most but not all internal border checks here: https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/schengen-area/temporary-reintroduction-border-control_en

@Dr.Snoopy sure, but are these border checks so thorough that they would detect that a person with a (for example) Spanish residence permit has spent the previous 91 days in (for example) Austria?  I would guess that the proportion is close to zero, if not actually zero.  Once it's apparent that the person being checked has a D visa or residence permit, the check is typically over.

"One is allowed 90 days, so the checks would need to happen several times over this period before anything (potentially nonconforming) is noticed": not necessarily.  If you're fined for walking across a street without using a pedestrian crossing, the police officer imposing the fine might come to suspect during the course of the encounter that you're living in that city while having a residence permit issued by a different country.  This happened to someone I know.

@phoog I have seen people denied entry for not having the right documents, so surely they can ask people to show they are entering the country legally, its on the applicants' side to show this.

@Dr.Snoopy we're discussing someone who has the right documents.  There's no way an officer at an internal border check is going to start asking people to prove that they haven't exceeded the 90/180 rule in the rest of the Schengen area.

Anyone who accused me of suggesting something illegal is wrong. I will repeat my own comment from above to make sure no one has any doubt about that: "2 - The OP is not spending over 90 days in a single place."

@phoog See comments above, for digital nomad visas, they might not give access to the whole Schengen area, and this would easily be caught in a internal Schengen border check.

@André " The OP is not spending over 90 days in a single place" But they would be spending more than 90 days outside of the country issuing the visa, and that would be a violation of the 90/180 rule. The rule applies to the whole Schengen area outside the country that issued the visa. So it would be very easy to violate the rules in this case.

@André someone with a national visa or residence permit for one Schengen country is not supposed to stay for more than 90 days out of any 180 in the entire rest of the Schengen area.  So, for example, if you have a visa or residence permit for Spain and you spend 46 days each in France and Germany, you've exceeded the limit without spending more than 90 says in either place.

@Dr.Snoopy "for digital nomad visas, they might not give access to the whole Schengen area": a digital nomad visa, like every D visa, allows the bearer to spend up to 90 days out of 180 in the rest of the Schengen area (a privilege that is of little use to a US citizen, as they already enjoy it).
